# spider crawling source code is different from those seen in the browser

Tags: scrapy

my spider crawling source code is different from those seen in the browser.

I'm sure that this information is not loaded by JS

this is my code:

```
import scrapy

class spider_chinaunicom(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'spider_chinaunicom'

def start_requests(self):
    self.item = SpiderChinaunicomItem()
    yield scrapy.Request(globalvar.chinaunicom_url%(globalvar.announcement_page),
                         method='POST',
                         body=json.dumps(globalvar.formdata),
                         callback=self.parse)

def parse(self, response):
    print(response.text)
```

and this is the source code in the browser.

```
<P style="FONT-FAMILY: ; COLOR: black; FONT-SIZE: 10.5pt; mso-hansi- 
font-family: " class=MsoNormal><span class="">
...
{this is the important message that i want to crawl}
...
</span></P>
```

But the result of the program runs is this

```
<P style="FONT-FAMILY: ; COLOR: black; FONT-SIZE: 10.5pt; mso-hansi- 
font-family: " class=MsoNormal><span class="">

<br><br>

</span></P>
```

it lost the information I wanted

Why does it lose the information I want

Comment: Are you sending the same cookies as a browser? What about the user agent? Can you post an example URL?

Comment: i have added user agent, but i didn't send the cookies,this is a url 
 http://www.chinaunicombidding.cn/jsp/cnceb/web/info1/detailNotice.jsp?id=2876703300000010571

Comment: This is another URL， http://www.chinaunicombidding.cn/jsp/cnceb/web/info1/detailNotice.jsp?id=4408703300000001141      some url i could get the information，but some didn't